# Problema con espacios finales en regEx

Tags: javascript, regex, validación

tengo esta función que me valida el nombre o apellidos de un usuario, pero tengo un problema con la regex: si añado espacios en blanco al final del nombre me da error. Puedo escribir nombres compuestos, los espacios entre los nombres no dan problemas pero si al final. Supongo que nadie lo haría pero podría darse el caso de escribir Juan+[teclaespacio]+[teclaespacio] y ahí me salta como error

```javascript
function validarNombre(valor) {
    if (
        /^([A-Za-zÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú]+['\-]{0,1}[A-Za-zÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú]+)(\s+([A-Za-zÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú]+['\-]{0,1}[A-Za-zÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú]+))*$/i.test(
            valor
        )
    ) {
        // alert("El nombre es correcto!.");
        return true;
    } else {
        // alert("El nombre no tiene el formato correcto!.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

¿Cómo podría solucionar el problema de los espacios en blanco al final de la expresión?

Gracias!

Comment: Tienes varias soluciones. La primera que se me ocurre es eliminar los espacios en blanco del inicio y final de la cadena. No veo la utilidad de tenerlos así que usa algo como `.test(valor.trim())` y los espacios en blanco al inicio y al final se eliminarán. La segunda opción es agregar `\s*` en tu expresión regular justo antes del símbolo de `$`. Por cierto no necesitas el `if`, simplifica tu código a `return /exp/.test(valor)`, el método test devuelve `true` o `false`.

Comment: Gracias Jaime, me parece muy buena opción la eliminación del if y ahora funciona la validación!

Comment: @JaimeMenendez deberías publicarlo como respuesta

Comment: No deberías permitir espacios en blanco antes o después en un campo del formulario. Si el usuario los introduce deberías o bien indicar el problema o bien eliminarlos del campo del formulario antes de enviarlo al motor (backend) o bien eliminarlos en el motor. Esto último lo obvio porque la validación en el lado del servidor debe hacerse siempre sí o sí, no debería ser una opción.